# JSF 2.1 Annotated ManagedBean not getting created

Tags: jsf-2

I have a simple JSF project that has an xhtml page which uses a managed bean that is configured with Annotation.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Authorization implements Serializable {
    private String greetings = "Hello World!";
    public String getGreetings() { return greetings; }
}
```

I'm trying to access this bean from the xhtml with the following EL:

```
<p:outputText value="#{authorization.greetings}" />
```

I'm also logging in the Authorization class with the java logging API just to see if anything happens. Even with logging in the Authorization constructor, no messages are being generated, abd the outputText shows nothing. It's like the bean does not even exists. I get no exceptions but no output either. However if I configure the bean frm faces-config it is working. My question is, why not with annotations?

P.S.: I'm using Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bean is not properly named :

```
Authoriztaion
```

should be replaced for

```
Authorization
```

**EDIT :**

As commented, the problem was related to the bad `ManagedBean` import. Should use this one :

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
```

Comment: Ah That's just misstyped in here not in the project. :-/

Comment: Have you recompiled and redeployed?

Comment: Yes, I recompiled & re-deployed the code like dozens of times. I've correted the typo in the original post.

Comment: Have you imported the right `ManagedBean` class ie : `import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;`?

Comment: yes, this was the problem... I had some annotation import instead of this. I tried to search for the problem elsewhere. Thank you very much for your help!